# Firefox showing strange behaviour in css margin padding not working

Tags: html, css

So i have alignment problem in mozilla Firefox only.All other browser showing good results.Actually the problem remains that loadingImage(bunny) is not showing any effect on  maring-bottom parameter in firefox.

```
 html, body {

       margin:0; padding:0;
       background-color: #000000;
}

#myCanvas {
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
top:0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;

margin: auto;
}
#loadingImage{
        color:#90B3DF;
        position: absolute;    
        padding-left: 00px;
        margin: auto;
        top:0;
        bottom: 220px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;

    }
```

While the html code is

```
        <span  id="sp1" style="width: 0%"></span>
        <div>
         <img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Smiley face" id="loadingImage" height="166" width="135">
        <h1 id="bolo">LOADING</h1>

        </div>


</div>
```

All the browsers are placing the bunny image above the loading bar but mozilla is showing exception ,an image like this probably

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufngd.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case, you would only want to set either the top or bottom of your absolutely positioned element. In this case that would be #loadingImage.

You have both top, and bottom set. If you're trying to get it to be positioned 220px from the top of what the #loadingImage position is relative to, use top. Otherwise use bottom, and remove top. From MDN:

- "If both top and bottom are specified (technically, not auto), top wins."
- "If both left and right are specified, left wins when direction is ltr (English, horizontal Japanese, etc.) and right wins when direction is rtl (Persian, Arabic, Hebrew, etc.)."

This is not to say you can not use top and bottom at the same time (or even left and right for that matter). But you would only do that specifically for when you want to fill the space between the two positions you are setting.

read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Also other general tips:

- Inline styling is generally a bad idea. I would recommend handling presentation inside a css file altogether. Makes your project more maintainable over time.
- padding: 0px is all thats necessary, don't have to use 00px
- Try to keep your HTML and CSS markup neatly spaced. This also goes back to having a more maintainable project over time. Example:

This is easier to read:

```
#myCanvas {
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Than:

```
#myCanvas {
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
top:0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;

margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Hey @Devin, you can specify both left and right etc. It will determine the size of an absolutely positioned box and can be pretty useful because padding doesn't interfere like when using percent.

Comment: Edited my answer to be more specific in how it actually works. If both top and bottom are set, top will always win. Likewise if both left and right are set, left will always win. Per MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Ah, I think you need to re-read that! It says 'Except for the case just described of absolutely positioned elements filling the available space'. If you try a test you'll see that it's dimensions are changed.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.Any idea why other browser are showing expected loading image rather then mozilla firefox.

Comment: @robC Today I learned something. Thank you, sir. I stand corrected. :)

Comment: @Devin.Removed the top margin And worked like charm.You are amazing .Keep rocking .Stay blessed!

Comment: @Devin no probs. Please remove the incorrect assertion though for future viewers.

Comment: Sorry for being noob but what can i remove ?

Comment: @YawrMailk my comment was to Devin. You don't need to do anything :)

Comment: @robC should be all set now.